# How to retrieve all Uid without currentUser?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I don't know how to retrieve all Uid. This is my data:

[image]

this is my snippet code to set the data:

```
reference = db.getReference("Attendance");
reference.child(id).child(uid).child.("Status").setValue(status);
```

any help thank you guys

Comment: What does the data mean? Specifically: what is the meaning of the `-LT....` level in your JSON? I understand it was generated by calling `push()`, but what's its meaning? Specifically: if you'd remove the `-LT...` value, could you still implement your use-case?

Comment: its function` -LT` to keep incoming data in sequence. because without `-LT` the data will enter randomly @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Ah OK. So timestamp is important. But if you'd add a timestamp property to each user, would that then still allow you to implement your use-case? The reason I'm asking is that it sounds like each UID should be under `/Attendance` only once, and that's easiest to enforce if you store `/Attendance/$uid: { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log all UIDs (and names) from the JSON:

```
reference = db.getReference("Attendance");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot idSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(idSnapshot.getKey());
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: idSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
                System.out.println(userSnapshot.child("Status/xname").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: does `userSnapshot.getKey()` take the Uid and id at once? and could i use `addValueEventListiener` ? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: `addValueEventListener` will work the same, but will keep listening for changes. I added a line printing each `id`.

Comment: sir, may i know, why there is no `child("Status")` ? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Woops.... I forgot that one in my code. Added it now. Thanks for spotting.